# How to git push in GitHub workflow reuse?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I use workflows to carry out simple tasks: downloading data, analyze them and store them in github. For this I use a main workflow which calls other workflows so that I can program the main workflow but also launch the other workflows manually if necessary.

Everything works well except the last step: the Git push. Indeed the commits are pushed to github but in the following workflow the previous commits disappear. At the end, only the very last commit of the last workflow remains. I think the `actions/checkout@main` has something to do with it but I don't see what's the problem.

Here is the code used :

**1. Main workflow**

```
name: WORKFLOW-NAME
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 4 1 * *'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  JOB1:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work1.yml

  JOB2:
    needs: JOB1
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work2.yml

  JOB3:
    needs: JOB2
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work3.yml
  
  JOB4:
    needs: JOB2
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work4.yml
```

**2. One of the workflows called  (work3.yml)**

```
name: JOB3
on:
  workflow_call:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  JOB3:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      
      - name: Run script
        run:  |
          ./SCRIPTS/script.ps1
```

**3. Example script with Git push (script.ps1)**

```
### SCRIPT
(...)
### Save to git
git config --local user.email "name@mail.com"
git config --local user.name "Username"
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin main -f
```

Comment: Does each job pushed files to the repository?

Comment: Yes, each job push files!

Comment: JOB1 and JOB2 run in sequence, when JOB3 and JOB4 need JOB2 to run. I would understand having conflicts between JOB3 and JOB4, as they run in parallel, but commits from JOB1 and JOB2 should still appear. Did you try using `fetch-depth: 0` just to check?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake on my part: JOB1 is not pushing. JOB2 pushes once, JOB3 pushes twice, and JOB4 pushes once.
Result: after the workflow without changing fetch, only the JOB4 commit is attached to the main branch, and with fetch 0 only the JOB3 commits are attached to the main branch. All other commits are present in GitHub but not attached to the branch.

Comment: Ok. Are other commits are present but associated to "no branch" on git?

Comment: Absolutely ! 
I created a public repo so you can view: https://github.com/A-d-r-i/stackoverflow77125168/ - You can see that only the commit from the last workflow is kept ( [2c7c50c](https://github.com/A-d-r-i/stackoverflow77125168/commit/2c7c50c) ). You can also see in the main workflow logs the other 3 commits not attached to a branch ( [c9fa6a1](https://github.com/A-d-r-i/stackoverflow77125168/commit/c9fa6a1) / [72b1901](https://github.com/A-d-r-i/stackoverflow77125168/commit/72b1901) / [4afbad5](https://github.com/A-d-r-i/stackoverflow77125168/commit/4afbad5) )

Comment: I'm trying to find some reference here to prevent unattached commits from github actions parallel workflow runs. A workaround could be to push the files back to another branch before opening a PR to the default branch, that could be merged automatically. But that sound too much for this issue.

Comment: I found an alternative by removing the parallel actions and pulling in workflows before running the scripts. I'll detail this in an answer. It's a little weird but it works.

Comment: Ok, so performing all the pushes in sequence resolves the problem. Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and @GuiFalourd's answers, the problem comes from the parallel execution of some workflows.
I therefore slightly changed my main workflow in order to remove the parallelism of the actions as well as the underlying workflows by adding a `git pull` action.

**1. Main workflow**

```
name: WORKFLOW-NAME
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 4 1 * *'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  JOB1:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work1.yml

  JOB2:
    needs: JOB1
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work2.yml

  JOB3:
    needs: JOB2
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work3.yml
  
  JOB4:
    needs: JOB3 ##### LINE OF CHANGE #####
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work4.yml
```

**2. One of the workflows called (work3.yml)**

```
name: JOB3
on:
  workflow_call:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  JOB3:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      
      - name: Pull & run script
        run:  |
          git pull origin main  ##### LINE OF CHANGE #####
          ./SCRIPTS/script.ps1
```